# Ambiguous call to method "Round(a: System.Double): System.Double ; Round(d: System.Decimal): System.Decimal"

Tags: .net, rounding, type-conversion, delphi-prism, oxygene

I am bit confused as to why calling Math.Round method would raise, "Ambiguous Call" compiler error.

Here is my offending code:

```
Math.Round((2000-((Splots[x].RawMin/4095)*2000))+200);
```

RawMin is Int32 data type.

I thought, Round method should return with Int32 value type.

Any hints or clues will be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the overload list for [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as4h66hd). There are two methods taking a single parameter:

```
double Round(double d)
decimal Round(decimal d)
```

Both are applicable when called with an `int` argument - but it's pointless to call the method when you've only got an `int` to start with, as it's already rounded.

I suspect you *actually* want to change how you're doing arithmetic, e.g. by performing the division operation in `double` arithmetic, which will then propagate to the other operations:

```
// Note the 4095.0 to make it a double
Math.Round((2000-((Splots[x].RawMin/4095.0)*2000))+200);
```

Without that, *all* the operations use integer arithmetic, which almost certainly wasn't what you wanted.

You'll still need to cast the result to `int` though. The range of `double` exceeds that of both `int` and `long`, which is why the return type of `Math.Round(double)` is `double`. In this case you "know" that the result will be in an appropriate range though, given the calculation.

Comment: Jon Skeet, I guess I assumed that since I am doing division, the result will alway come out as decimal. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @digitalanalog: Nope - if you're using `int` operands, the division is performed in integers; if you're using `decimal` operands, it's performed in `decimal`; if you're using `double` operands, it's performed in `double`. If you have `int` and `double`, the `int` is promoted to `double` first, which is the situation in my suggested code.